# Definir Entidade Account em dotnet

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, entity-framework

Olá,

Tenho que definir uma entity account para um microserviço de um software de retalho.
Uma account pode ser do tipo:

- **Individual**
- **Familia**
- **Empresa**

Sendo o tipo **individual**  é composto pelos os campos tradicionais, que representam um utilizador:

- Id
- Email
- Nome
- Morada
- Contacto
- Data de nascimento

O tipo **Familia** é composto por: um ou vários utilizadores, cada utilizador podes associar outro s utilizadores e assim criar **Familias**. O utilizador que cria a Familia fica como administrador da familia e só ele pode adicionar ou apagar elementos da Familia.

O tipo **Empresa** é uma conta que pode conter um ou vários utilizadores associados e que é criada pela própria empresa com os seguintes campos:

- Id
- Nome
- Email
- Morada
- Contacto

No vosso entendimento qual é a melhor forma de definir as entidades no c# (.Net Core) ?

Devo separar o conceito Utilizador e Account ?

Defino a entidade Account que representa os três tipos ? Neste caso, como defino a Familia?

Não sei se existe um padrão que me pode ajudar a definir de uma forma eficiente os diferentes tipos de accounts.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o conceito de *herança* em orientação a objetos. Como eu faria:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    // Todos os outros atributos comuns a todas entidades
 }

public class Individual : Account
{
     public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
     // Atributos específicos dessa entidade
}

public class Empresa : Account 
{
    // Atributos específicos dessa entidade
}

public class Familia
{
    public int IndividualId { get; set; }.  //Id do Administrador
    public Individual Individual { get; set; } // Administrador
    public IEnumerable<Individual> Individuals { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela respota! Mas como representaria esse esquema numa base de dados (nosql)?